# Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email

Quero enviar e-mails do *localhost*.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<h1> Olá mundo!</h1>

<?php

$enviar = mail( "meuemail@gmail.com", "nada não", "teste somente");

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu fui no `php.ini` e coloquei assim:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = meuemail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Qual erro acontece meu caro ?

Comment: Nem erro acontece. Eu atualizo a página e só aparece o cabeçalho que coloquei.

Comment: Faz `var_dump($enviar);` antes de fechares o PHP e vê o que acontece.

Comment: Retorna booleano falso.

Comment: um dos problemas é que o smtp do gmail não trabalha na porta 25 aonde a função mais não ira conseguir enviar, retornando sempre bool false

Comment: Eu fiz tudo de acordo a resposta @Otto, reiniciei o apache no final. Eu uso o wampstack, coloquei a pasata "sendamil" no C, coloquei dentro do htdocs, sempre mudando o caminho no arquivo "php.ini" e nada...

Comment: Fiz vários testes e nem erro aparece na página.

Comment: Quando tentou enviar com o phpMailer, lembrou de ativar a extensão `php_openssl.dll` no `php.ini`? É necessária para envio por SMTP autenticado (ex.: gmail na porta 587).

Comment: Lembrei, mas na verdade já estava descomentada quando fui ver.

Comment: E aquele exemplo do gmail que vem com o phpMailer, na pasta `examples`, dá qual erro pra ti?

Comment: @Thomas Eu consegui enviar usando o exemplo que vem dentro do próprio phpmailer.

Comment: E voce precisou mudar a porta do teu servidor pra isso?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bom vou mostrar o jeito que fiz usando o gmail, PHPMailer e WampServer.

1º habilitar o `ssl_module` no apache. Para Habilitar abra o arquivo `httpd.conf` do apache e procure a seguinte linha no arquivo `#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`, retire o simbolo `#` para habilitar.

2º Habilitar as seguintes extensões no php.ini `php_openssl`, `php_sockets` e `php_smtp`(caso tenha), no meu caso não tem. Para habilitar as extensões procure elas no php.ini e retire o `;` da frente. As extensões estão assim no php.ini `;extension=php_openssl.dll`, `;extension=php_sockets.dll`.

3º Baixar o PHPMailer no [GitHub](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), descompacte-o e pegue as seguintes classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4º Codificar.

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php'); //chama a classe de onde você a colocou.

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // instancia a classe PHPMailer

$mail->IsSMTP();

//configuração do gmail
$mail->Port = '465'; //porta usada pelo gmail.
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//configuração do usuário do gmail
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'seuemail@gmail.com'; // usuario gmail.   
$mail->Password = 'suasenhadogmail'; // senha do email.

$mail->SingleTo = true; 

// configuração do email a ver enviado.
$mail->From = "Mensagem de email, pode vim por uma variavel."; 
$mail->FromName = "Nome do remetente."; 

$mail->addAddress("destinatario@hotmail.com"); // email do destinatario.

$mail->Subject = "Aqui vai o assunto do email, pode vim atraves de variavel."; 
$mail->Body = "Aqui vai a mensagem, que tambem pode vim por variavel.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Erro ao enviar Email:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

A primeira vez que rodei o código acima me retornou o seguinte erro:
`SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`.

Para resolve-lo fui no meu email e encontrei a seguinte mensagem do gmail.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja o gmail bloqueou minha tentativa de conexão apartir do localhost.

para evitar esse erro acessei [configurações de segurança](https://www.google.com/settings/security) do gmail e fui na parte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acessei as configurações e ativei como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e tentei reenviar o email apartir do localhost novamente, enviei para mim mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e agora enviei para uma outra conta minha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Essa foi a maneira que eu fiz para enviar email através do localhost.**

### OBS:

Estou usando o WampServer, creio que funciona em qualquer outro servidor, é somente saber onde o servidor coloca o arquivo `httpd` do apache e o `php.ini`, e habilitar os módulos e extensões.

### OBS 2:

As classes do PHPMailer vão no seu projeto.

Minha resposta foi baseada neste [tutorial](http://llucasdesenvolvimento.com/mundoweb/enviar-e-mail-usando-o-servidor-wamp/).

Comment: Eu consegui enviar usando o exemplo que vem dentro do próprio phpmailer.

Comment: Obrigado, peguei algumas dicas de sua resposta.

Comment: @I Wanna Know, Que bom que minha resposta lhe ajudou de alguma forma. =)

Comment: MeuChapeu, show de bola o seu tutorial. Precisei descomentar tb a linha ;extension_dir = "ext" do php.ini para entao funcionar, de resto foi so seguir o q vc escreveu =DDD

Comment: @GregoryIyama, =P fico feliz em saber que lhe foi util.

Answer (score 8):

Os passos foram tirados e adaptados do comentário original em PHP.net:

1 - Baixe o arquivo sendmail.zip de http://glob.com.au/sendmail/. Se você usa XAMPP, ele já vem incluído (pule então o passo 2).

2 - Descompacte para alguma pasta do Windows, mas de preferência com nomes curtos (como por exemplo C:\sendmail).

3 - Edite seu PHP.ini (no WAMP/XAMPP, acesse pelo menu próprio), e configure como abaixo (repare que vamos usar configurações do Sendmail nos Unix):
[mail function] 
; For Win32 only. 
;SMTP =

; For Win32 only. 
;sendmail_from =

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i"). 
sendmail_path = "C:\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters 
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of 
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode. 
;mail.force_extra_paramaters =

4 - Salve suas alterações do PHP.ini.

5 - Agora abra o arquivo SENDMAIL.ini e edite os seguintes campos:
smtp_server: o endereço do servidor SMTP;
smtp_port: a porta do servidor SMTP;
default_domain: o domínio do seu email;
pop3_server: o endereço do servidor POP3;
pop3_username: seu email;
pop3_password: sua senha.
Pegue estas informações com seu provedor de email. No caso do Gmail, pegue as informações da seguinte página de ajuda: Gmail: Configurando o Outlook Express.

```
[sendmail] 

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server, 
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup) 
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to 
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling 
; application. 

smtp_server=smtp.yourdomain.com 

; smtp port (normally 25) 
; ATENÇÃO: PARA SSL É 465 
; ATENÇÃO: PARA GMAIL É 587 (E APENAS COM SSL)! 

smtp_port=25 

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry 
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided 
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify 

default_domain=yourdomain.com 

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe) 
; uncomment to enable logging 
; error_logfile=sendmail_error.log 

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe) 
; uncomment to enable debugging 
; debug_logfile=sendmail_debug.log 

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines 

;auth_username= 
;auth_password= 

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines 

pop3_server=pop.yourdomain.com 
pop3_username=you@yourdomain.com 
pop3_password=mysecretpassword 

; to force the sender to always be the following email address, uncomment and 
; populate with a valid email address.  this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" 
; command, it won't modify the "From: " header of the message content 

force_sender=you@yourdomain.com 

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo 
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required 

hostname=
```

6 - Reinicie o Apache

7 - Alguns serviços de email precisam de configuração para permitir o acesso POP3. No Gmail, por exemplo, execute os passos descritos em "Enabling POP".

Comment: Eu tinha baixado o sendmail. Assisti uma aula que ensinava exatamente isso, mas não sabia exatamente onde pegar as informações de domínio e tals. Vou olhar agora e já respondo.

Comment: Só estou com uma dúvida: o domínio d emeu e-mail é meu próprio e-mail?

Comment: Tentei colocar meu e-mail e somente "gmail.com", mas não funcionou.

Comment: lembrando que o gmail a porta é 587 somente com SSL ativo .... ainda aconcelho a enviar utilizando uma biblioteca tipo phpmailer ou swiftmailer

Comment: para ativar o SSL descomenta essa linha "ssl  = alway use SSL"?

Comment: da uma lida nesse link http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp  tem informações exatamente sobre o gmail

Comment: Tava lendo, mas o cara pede pra fazer o download do stunnel, na página de download tem vários links, eu escolhi um... Diz que é para mudar o arquivo config, mas não especifica o quê. Vou continuar pesquisando para ver se consigo algo mais entendível. Grato.

Comment: Eu consegui enviar usando o exemplo que vem dentro do próprio phpmailer.

Answer (score 8):

No Windows 8 você precisará do **Stunnel** para fazer o **Sendmail** funcionar corretamente com o Gmail uma vez que este retirou o suporte para **v2** como é utilizado pelo sendmail, acompanhe o passo-a-passo abaixo e acredito que terás sucesso:

Você irá precisar:

- WAMP Servidor;
- Sendmail;
- Stunnel;
- Uma conta de e-mail do Gmail (lógico).

Depois de instalado o WAMP crie dentro do diretório principal do WAMP uma pasta com o nome "**sendmail**", por exemplo ***D:\wamp\sendmail***, caso tenha instalado o WAMP na unidade "***D:***".

Coloque os arquivos do sendmail na nova pasta criada, procure pelo arquivo de configuração **sendmail.ini** e abra-o para editar conforme abaixo.

Altere os seguintes valores:

```
smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=none
auth_username=seu_email@gmail.com
auth_password=sua_senha
```

Salve e feche o arquivo **sendmail.ini**

Configurado o Sendmail é hora de configurar o **php.ini** alterando os seguintes valores:

```
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_path = "D:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

> Lembrando que o caminho "D:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe" pode ser
>   diferente dependendo da unidade onde você instalou o WAMP.

Salve e feche o arquivo **php.ini** e reinicie os serviços do WAMP.

Agora vem a dica para funcionar no Windows 8.

1. Baixe o Stunnel (https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html) e instale no seu computador;
2. Na pasta do Stunnel procure pelo arquivo ***stunnel.conf***, deverá estar em **C:\Arquivos de Programas\stunnel** (64bits) ou **C:\Program Files (x86)\stunnel** (32bits);

> **DICA:** Para editar este arquivo você precisará de permissões especiais, portanto será necessário copiá-lo para a **Área de Trabalho** para só então editá-lo e depois de editado sobrescrevê-lo na pasta de origem.

Após copiar o arquivo abra-o e edite as seguintes configurações:

```
cert = stunnel.pem
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
key = stunnel.pem

[ssmtp]
accept  = 465
connect = 25

[gmail-smtp]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:25
connect = smtp.gmail.com:465

// Para verificar os registros, você pode habilitar a opção de debug
// que fica no início do arquivo
debug = 7
output = stunnel.log
```

> **DICA:** Caso habilite a opção de debug será necessário criar o arquivo stunnel.log se ele não existir e dar as devidas permissões do seu usuário.

Salve, feche o arquivo **stunnel.conf** e execute o "**Stunnel.exe**".

Rode o seu script de envio de e-mail PHP e verifique se deu certo!

> No link https://github.com/mjpsolucoes/confSendmailStunnelWin8 eu disponibilizei os meus arquivos de configuração [php.ini (parcial), sendmail.ini, stunnel.conf] para você analisar!

Boa sorte!!!

Comment: Eu consegui enviar usando o exemplo que vem dentro do próprio phpmailer.

Comment: Blz! Agora vi sua edição...