# Como fazer o PHPMailer enviar pelo meu próprio servidor?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Eu fiz a pergunta abaixo e após tentar várias maneiras de enviar e-mail pelo localhost
consegui com o PHPMailer:

[Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php)

No entanto eu consegui através do exemplo próprio para o Gmail que fica dentro da pasta 'examples" do PHPMailer.

Eu queria saber o seguinte, se eu construir um pequeno site usando o PHPMailer quando eu for hospedar terei que upar as classes do PHPMailer não é isso?

Sei que é uma pergunta um tanto óbvia, mas minha preocupação é se posso aproveitar o código configurado para o Gmail.

É só mudar o servidor e tals?

```
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a.
RFC4409 SMTP   submission $mail->Port = 587;
```

Nessas linhas eu colocarei o servidor onde eu hospedarei meu site?

Comment: Você quer continuar mandando pelo Gmail a partir do seu servidor, ou não?

Comment: Cada servidor pode ter seus requisitos próprios. Mas me parece que seu código exemplo está usando o SMTP do Gmail, e não do seu próprio servidor. Poderia elaborar melhor?

Comment: Não quero continuar mandando pelo gmail. É exatamente essa  a questão: para mandar pelo servidor eu preciso alterar só umas linha sou teria que refazer todo o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, sim, você pode (e é interessante) reaproveitar o código.

Você só precisará editar as partes referentes a configuração do servidor de envio de emails, conforme você descreveu em sua postagem.

Comment: Obrigado, vou só esperar se alguém coloca algo adicional.

Comment: Ah, fazendo uma releitura, acho que você se confundiu: as linhas descritas devem ser configuradas para o servidor de envio de emails (SMTP). Se o servidor onde você hospeda seu site tem um servidor SMTP, então você poderá configurar o arquivo conforme as configurações do seu servidor.

Comment: e se não for SMTP? Mudo outra parte?

Comment: O PHPMailer só suporta SMTP e [POP before SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP). Se você quiser usar o POP before SMTP, será necessário realizar algumas alterações em seu código. Sugiro que utilize o [exemplo provido pelos desenvolvedores](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/pop_before_smtp.phps).