# Código PHP com falha: Indica Email Enviado Mas não envia nada

Tags: php, phpmailer

Quero completar esse código para enviar um arquivo sempre que uma determinada página for aberta.

```
<?php

// Incluir a classe no teu ficheiro
require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';

// Instanciar a classe para envio de email
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Vamos tentar realizar o envio
try {

    // Remetente
    $mail->AddReplyTo('meu@hotmail.com', 'Meu Nome');
    $mail->SetFrom('meu@hotmail.com', 'Meu Nome');



    // Destinatário
    $mail->AddAddress('meu@hotmail.com', 'Destinatário');

    // Assunto
    $mail->Subject = 'Segue ficheiro anexo com XPTO';

    // Mensagem para clientes de email sem suporte a HTML
    $mail->AltBody = 'Em anexo o ficheiro com XPTO.';

    // Mensagem para clientes de email com suporte a HTML
    $mail->MsgHTML('<p>Em anexo o ficheiro com XPTO.</p>');

    // Adicionar anexo
    $caminho = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/envio_de_arquivo_automatico/PHP_ENVIAR_ARQUIVO_POR_EMAIL/PHPMAILER/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailer-master/';
    $ficheiro = 'Documento2.docx';

    $mail->AddAttachment($caminho.$ficheiro);

    // Enviar email
    $mail->Send();

    echo "Mensagem enviada!";
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    // Mensagens de erro do PHPMailer
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    // Outras mensagens de erro
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: O email é enviado e o anexo não aparece? ou o email não é enviado? obs no caminha use essa barra ``\\` para especificar as pastas.

Comment: O Email não chega a ser enviado. E alterando a / por \ da erro: erro de sintaxe, inesperado 'Documento2'

Comment: Não sei se faz diferença mas estou rodando em LOCALHOST.

Comment: O servidor de email está configurado? talvez [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40858/91) ajude

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas continuo a conferir se não esqueci nada.

Comment: Fora isso so a barra mesmo, ou vc usa aspas duplas ou escapa ela assim `C:\\pasta\\arquivo.txt `

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas ainda não deu certo.

Comment: Se não há mensagem alguma de erro em lugar algum do PHP (inclusive logs de erro do Apache), é provável que seu servidor SMTP esteja mal configurado. Concordo com o @rray sobre a `/`: você deve substituí-las por `\\`, pois está na plataforma Windows.

Comment: Brigado povo consegui, na verdade eu mudei o código um pouco.

Comment: $host = 'smtp.live.com';
     $username = 'meu@hotmail.com';
     $password = 'SENHA';
     $port = 587;
     $secure = 'tls';

     $from = $username;
     $fromName = 'Meu Nome';

Comment: $mail->From = $from;
     $mail->FromName = $fromName;

     $mail->isSMTP();
     $mail->Host = $host;
     $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
     $mail->Username = $username;
     $mail->Password = $password;
     $mail->Port = $port;
     $mail->SMTPSecure = $secure;

Comment: // Adicionar anexo
    $caminho = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\envio_de_arquivo_automatico\\PHP_ENVIAR_ARQUIVO_POR_EMAIL\\PHPMAILER\\PHPMailer-master\\PHPMailer-master\\;
    $ficheiro = 'Documento2.docx';