# Função Mail PHP não funciona

Tags: php, html, email

Olá, tenho tentado enviar um email através da função mail do PHP, mas nada funciona, e após pesquisar um pouco, achei um site que dizia que era necessário ter um quinto parâmetro, sendo ele o email que receberá a mensagem, precedido de um  `-f`, e nem assim funciona, eis o que tenho até o momento:

```
$dest = "reeducate_cursos@hotmail.com";
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.1 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
$header .= "From: $email \r\n"; 
$header .= "Return-Path: $email \r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: $dest \r\n"; 
$msg = $_POST['text'];

$mail = mail($dest, $assunto, $msg, $header, -f$dest);
```

E não faço a menor ideia do que possa ser, já tentei tanta coisa...

Comment: Use o PHPMailer, vc deverá informar a configuração de SMTP
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/enviar-e-mails-pelo-php-usando-o-phpmailer/

Comment: Antes de tudo, você precisa configurar o arquivo `php.ini` com os parâmetros do seu server smtp

Comment: Você precisa fornecer mais detalhes do seu ambiente, é windows? é um host externo ou localhost?

Comment: @rray estou enviando de um windows utilizando o xampp(localhost).

Comment: [Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40858/91)

Comment: Tenta ultilizar o sendgrid "https://sendgrid.com/", provavelmente este seu código é de algum template aleatório, e normalmente essas funções em php de envio de e-mail nunca funcionam.

Answer (score 3):

Eu uso dessa forma, e transformando em base64 o email.

```
    $para="php@gmail.com";
    $assunto ="assunto Teste";
    $html="Olá esse é o conteudo do email";
    $headers = "From: Email do teste<meuemail@dominio.com> \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To:meuemail@dominio.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= rtrim(chunk_split(base64_encode($html)));

    $ok = mail($para , $assunto,'',$headers);
    echo $ok;
```