# Erro a mandar email - SMTP

Tags: php

Estou a tentar mandar um email de verificação. Mas dame um erro:

Tenho este codigo:

```
/*Define constant to connect to database */
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'forum');
/*Default time zone ,to be able to send mail */
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

/*You might not need this */
ini_set('SMTP', "mail.myt.mu"); // Overide The Default Php.ini settings for   sending mail


//This is the address that will appear coming from ( Sender )
define('EMAIL', 'mariocozta@gmail.com');

/*Define the root url where the script will be found such as    http://website.com or http://website.com/Folder/ */
DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://localhost');


// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
DATABASE_NAME);

if (!$dbc) {
trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

?>
```

E' a primeira vez que tento enviar um email por php. Alguem sabe o problem?

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "mail.myt.mu" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\1-Registration system Modify\index.php on line 69
```

Estou a utilizar o easy php.

Answer (score -2):

Esse erro ocorre porque você não configurou o envio local do SMTP. Embora seja possível, eu acho um desperdício de tempo. Porque quando você enviar para um servidor, esse problema já não irá mais existir, contanto que seu código esteja correto claro.

Caso queira mesmo configurar localmente, segue uma pergunta semelhante com o uso do PHPMailer:

[Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40858/41345)