# PHP - Envio de formulário por e-mail

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email

Eu queria saber como faço no php para que um formulário html seja enviado a mim por e-mail, eu procurei tutoriais no youtube, mas todos eles só funcionam com um host, eu tentei emular um servidor e não consegui rodar a ação de envio, gostaria de saber como faço pra funcionar, mesmo usando localhost, por exemplo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom vou mostrar o jeito que fiz usando o gmail, PHPMailer e WampServer.

1º habilitar o `ssl_module` no apache. Para Habilitar abra o arquivo `httpd.conf` do apache e procure a seguinte linha no arquivo `#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so`, retire o simbolo `#` para habilitar.

2º Habilitar as seguintes extensões no php.ini `php_openssl`, `php_sockets` e `php_smtp`(caso tenha), no meu caso não tem. Para habilitar as extensões procure elas no php.ini e retire o `;` da frente. As extensões estão assim no php.ini `;extension=php_openssl.dll`, `;extension=php_sockets.dll`.

3º Baixar o PHPMailer no [GitHub](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), descompacte-o e pegue as seguintes classes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4º Codificar.

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php'); //chama a classe de onde você a colocou.

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // instancia a classe PHPMailer

$mail->IsSMTP();

//configuração do gmail
$mail->Port = '465'; //porta usada pelo gmail.
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//configuração do usuário do gmail
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'seuemail@gmail.com'; // usuario gmail.   
$mail->Password = 'suasenhadogmail'; // senha do email.

$mail->SingleTo = true; 

// configuração do email a ver enviado.
$mail->From = "Mensagem de email, pode vim por uma variavel."; 
$mail->FromName = "Nome do remetente."; 

$mail->addAddress("destinatario@hotmail.com"); // email do destinatario.

$mail->Subject = "Aqui vai o assunto do email, pode vim atraves de variavel."; 
$mail->Body = "Aqui vai a mensagem, que tambem pode vim por variavel.";

if(!$mail->Send())
    echo "Erro ao enviar Email:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

A primeira vez que rodei o código acima me retornou o seguinte erro:
`SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`.

Para resolve-lo fui no meu email e encontrei a seguinte mensagem do gmail.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja o gmail bloqueou minha tentativa de conexão apartir do localhost.

para evitar esse erro acessei [configurações de segurança](https://www.google.com/settings/security) do gmail e fui na parte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

acessei as configurações e ativei como na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e tentei reenviar o email apartir do localhost novamente, enviei para mim mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e agora enviei para uma outra conta minha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Essa foi a maneira que eu fiz para enviar email através do localhost.**

### OBS:

Estou usando o WampServer, creio que funciona em qualquer outro servidor, é somente saber onde o servidor coloca o arquivo `httpd` do apache e o `php.ini`, e habilitar os módulos e extensões.

### OBS 2:

As classes do PHPMailer vão no seu projeto.

Minha resposta foi baseada neste [tutorial](http://llucasdesenvolvimento.com/mundoweb/enviar-e-mail-usando-o-servidor-wamp/).

Comment: funcionou, obrigado! :D

Comment: que bom, por nada

Answer (score 0):

Fala Murilo!

Da uma olhada nesse post aqui do stackoverflow mesmo me parece similar ao seu problema, certo ?

[Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php)

Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Você até pode enviar usando localhost, porém, dificilmente este e-mail será recebido por algum provedor devido a filtros anti-spam e configurações de SPF e DKIM.

A função básica para envio de emails em PHP é esta:

```html
mail ( "email@destino.com", "assunto","corpo do email","From: remetente@email.com" );
```

A lib mais segura e completa pra enviar emails em PHP é o PHPMailer.

Você pode fazer o download do PHPMailer pelo [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) ou então por este [link direto](https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PHPMailer-master.zip).

Segue o código-fonte exemplo. Você precisa alterar nele o endereço do SMTP, login , senha, etc. de acordo com seu provedor de hospedagem.

```html
<?php
 
// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na mesma pasta do arquivo php
include "PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
 
// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
 
// Método de envio
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "localhost"; 
$mail->Port = 25; 
 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'francisco@meusitemodelo.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'senha-do-email'; 
 
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
 'ssl' => array(
 'verify_peer' => false,
 'verify_peer_name' => false,
 'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);

// $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
 
// Define o remetente
$mail->From = "francisco@meusitemodelo.com"; 
$mail->FromName = "Francisco"; 
 
// Define o(s) destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('maria@gmail.com', 'Maria');
//$mail->AddAddress('fernando@email.com');
 
        
$mail->IsHTML(true);
 
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 
$mail->Subject = "Assunto da mensagem"; 
 
$mail->Body = 'Corpo do email em html.<br><br><font color=blue>Teste de cores</font><br><br><img src="http://meusitemodelo.com/imagem.jpg">';
 
     
// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();
 
 
// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {
     echo "Seu email foi enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
     echo "Houve um erro enviando o email: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
 
?>
```

Você pode ver mais informações detalhadas sobre cada parametro neste artigo: https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/enviar-email-php-com-phpmailer-smtp/