# Erro ao enviar mensagem em php

Tags: php

Boa noite criei um arquivo teste para eu aprender como fazer um envio de formulário para um email através de php e quando eu executo pelo easyPHP Devserver 16.1.1 e aperto o botão enviar a página fica em branca

e não chega no meu email... qual seria o problema, estou colocando os arquivos abaixo

o meu arquivo -

index.html :

```
  <html>

<head>
    <title>Enviar email em php</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div id="contato_form">
        <form action="enviar.php" name="form_contato" method="post">
            <p class="titulo">Fomulario <small class="asteristico">* Campos obrigatorios</small></p>

            <p>Nome*:
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="nome" />

            </p>


            <p>Email*:
                <br/>
                <input type="email" name="email" />

            </p>


            <p>Telefone*:
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="telefone" />

            </p>

            <br />


            <span>Opcoes</span>
            <br/>

            <select name="escolhas">
                <option value="Opcao 1">Opcao 1</option>

                <option value="Opcao 2">Opcao 2</option>

            </select>

            <br/>

            <p>Mensagem:</p>
            <br />

            <textarea name="msg"></textarea>


            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <input type="reset" value="Limpar" />

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

enviar.php -

```
<? php
    //Variaveis
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$opcoes = $_POST['escolhas'];
$mensagem = $_POST['msg'];
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:I:S');


// Enviar

// email para quem sera enviado o formulario
$emailsenviar = "camposnicolas45@gmail.com";
$destino = $emailsenviar;
$assunto = "contato teste";


// e necessario indicar que o formato do email e html

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n' . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n' . 'From: $nome';

$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $headers);
if($enviaremail) {
    $mgm = "Email enviado com sucesso";

} else {
    $mgm = "error ao enviar";
    echo "";

}


    ?>
```

Creio que o local que pode estar dando problema seria no arquivo enviar.php

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n' . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n' . 'From: $nome';

$enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $headers);
if($enviaremail) {
    $mgm = "Email enviado com sucesso";

} else {
    $mgm = "error ao enviar";
    echo "";

}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar... obrigado.

Comment: qual o erro? só aparece a mensagem que voce postou acima? olha minha nova resposta

Comment: Sim... quando eu clico no botão enviar ele aparece um trecho do código php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após conversar com Nathan no Chat, descobri que a questão é que ele estava tentando enviar o email da máquina local dele sem configurar nenhum servidor de email.

Então recomendei ao mesmo que procurasse um tutorial mais específico e recomendei que ele estudasse por esse outro tópico: [Como enviar e-mail do localhost usando a função mail do PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php)

Comment: Então amigo tinha corrigido essa parte, quando eu executo ele aparece essa parte **'; $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $headers); if($enviaremail) { $mgm = "Email enviado com sucesso"; } else { $mgm = "error ao enviar"; echo ""; } ?>**... tinha editado minha pergunta, da uma olhada lá, obrigado por tentar

Comment: Você postou a linha que está com erro. Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: alterei a resposta, ve se resolve

Comment: Não funcionou amigo... alterei a minha pergunta acima indicando o local de onde acho que pode ser o erro.

Comment: olha a alteração novamente. ainda to desconfiado da concatenação

Comment: vou tentar só mais essa vez, vê o código agora. se não der eu desisto. to aguardando a resposta

Comment: Coloquei de uma forma que quando clico no botao enviar a pagina fica em branca... vou alterar a pergunta ai da uma olhada.

Comment: Pronto @Italo Rodrigo

Comment: a página fica em branco porque teu echo tava errado, corrigi ele na minha resposta

Comment: é mudou nada não... mas obrigado por você está aqui tentando me ajudar.

Comment: nao mostra mais nada? voce fez a alteração no echo?

Comment: Coloquei conforme você disse e mesmo assim a pagina fica em branco quando eu envio

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50356/discussion-between-italo-rodrigo-and-nathan).