# php e ajax envio de email

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentanto enviar email da minha pagina porém ela não me retorna nenhuma mensagem se deu sucesso ou não, estou usando php junto com bootstrapvalidation e ajax para encaminhar as informações para minha pagina do php.

JS

```
// Contact Form Scripts

$(function() {

$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    var email = $("input#email").val();
    var assunto = $("input#assunto").val();
    var message = $("textarea#message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            name: name,
            assunto:assunto,
            email: email,
            message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            // Success message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
            $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Sua mensagem foi enviada, em breve entraremos em contato.. </strong>");
            $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');

            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function() {

            // Fail message
            $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
            $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
            //clear all fields
            $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
        },
    });
},
filter: function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).tab("show");
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
 $('#name').focus(function() {
 $('#success').html('');
 });
```

HTML

```
<form action="mail/contact_me.php" method="post"      name="sentMessage"     id="contactForm" novalidate>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, informe seu nome.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, informe seu e-mail.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" class="form-control" placeholder="ASSUNTO*" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, informe um assunto.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Mensagem *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Por favor, insira uma mensagem."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="success">teste</div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php

    /*Checa se os campos estao vazios*/
    if (empty($_POST['name']) ||
            empty($_POST['email']) ||
            empty($_POST['assunto']) ||
            empty($_POST['message']) ||
            !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "No arguments Provided!";
        return false;
    }

    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $assunto = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['assunto']));
    $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

    /*Configurações de envio de Email*/

    $to = 'contatothsolution@gmail.com'; /*Email de Recebimento*/
    $email_subject = "Formulario de Contato"; /*Assunto do Email*/

    $email_body = "Nome: $name\n"
            . "Email: $email_address\n"
            . "Assunto: $assunto\n\n"
            . "Mensagem:\n$message";
    $headers = "From: " . $email_address . "\n"; /*Email de quem enviou*/
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
    mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    return true;
```

Comment: Verifique por meio de um "alert" ou "console.log" se o fluxo de execução está chegando até a parte onde a requisição é enviada. E nos dois eventos do ajax.

Comment: @mauhumor, verificando o console log encontrei esse erro `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacia\mail\contact_me.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />`

Answer (score 0):

Veja que independente do valor que `mail` retornará, o resultado está sendo verdadeiro, por causa de `return true;` no final do seu código. A documentação de `mail` informa o seguinte:

> Retorna TRUE se o email foi aceito com sucesso para entrega, FALSE caso contrário. É importante notar que somente pelo o email ser aceito para entrega, não significa que o email alcancará o destino esperado.

Altere as dulas últimas linhas do código para esta:

```
if(@mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers)) return true; else return false;
```

**Edit:**
Obs: Para que obtenha o retorno, coloque todo o código dentro de uma função.

Comment: Na verdade o `return` está errado tanto na pergunta quanto na sua resposta, `return` só funciona se estiver em uma função ou se for o retorno de um `include`/`require`. Isto não vai resolver o problema da pergunta `return true; else return false;` e não vai enviar nada para o corpo da resposta no Ajax.

Comment: Isso mesmo Guilherme, depois de concluir a resposta é que percebi que o bloco de código não estava dentro de uma função. Mas eu já tinha feito a edição.

Comment: Eu tenho em outro  projeto  esse script de envio e funciona perfeitamente. Não sei por que nesse projeto não esta funcionando.

Comment: @fabricio isso deve resolver http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40858/3635 pois pela sua mensagem de erro `<br /> <b>Warning</b>: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\farmacia\mail\contact_me.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />` o provavel é que vc esteja tentando enviar diretamente do seu computador e não de um servidor

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, farei essas modificações e postarei o resultado, mas o estranho é que eu tenho um outro projeto nesse mesmo computador que funciona perfeitamente com esse script.

Comment: @fabricio mas chega algum email para o destinatário? O STMP para envio está configurado no teu computador?

Comment: usando pelo localhost não chega, porém hospedado sim. Também tentei hospedar esse projeto e mesmo assim não obtive sucesso.