# Fiz esse código para enviar um email automático para o cadastrado na db . O cadastro está ok, mas o email não vai para o cliente. O que está errado?

Tags: php, envio-de-email

codigo php

```
<?php

include "conectar.php";


//comando para iserir dados direto do formulário para o banco de dados

$vnome=$_POST['nome'];
$vcpf=$_POST['cpf'];
$videntidade=$_POST["identidade"];
$vtelefone=$_POST["telefone"];
$vcelular=$_POST["celular"];
$vemail=$_POST["email"];
$vcep=$_POST["cep"];
$vendereco=$_POST["endereco"];
$vcomplemento=$_POST["complemento"];
$vbairro=$_POST["bairro"];
$vcidade=$_POST["cidade"];
$vuf=$_POST["uf"];
$vsexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$vidade=$_POST["idade"];
$vpeso=$_POST["peso"];


$sql="INSERT INTO solidario VALUES (NULL, '$vnome', '$vcpf', '$videntidade', '$vtelefone', '$vcelular', '$vemail', '$vcep', '$vendereco', '$vcomplemento', '$vbairro', '$vcidade', '$vuf', '$vsexo', '$vidade', '$vpeso')";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$num=mysqli_affected_rows($con);

if($num == 1){

mail('contato@beefladesign.com.br',$vnome,$vcpf, 'FROM:$vemail');
echo"<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=index.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Seu cadastrado foi realizado com sucesso!.\");
                </script>

            ";  

}else{
    echo"   <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=index.php'>
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"seu CPF já foi cadastrado!.\");
                </script>                   
            ";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Acho que o erro está nos parâmetros da função mail ela possui 3 `mail(string $to, string $subject, string $message)` você eatá passando 4 e um `echo` em baixo, mas não sei se tu eatá fazendo de algum outro modo que não conheço

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja por causa do `'FROM:$vemail'`, [quando você usa `'` o PHP não interpreta nada dentro dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php).

Altere para:

```
'FROM: '.$vemail
```

ou

```
"FROM: $vemail"
```

*Deveria* de funcionar. Porém, existe um outro detalhe, você está definindo o FROM e não o TO. Isso é, o `$vemail` é que está "enviando" a mensagem e não recebendo, acredito que você deve fazer algo como:

```
mail($vemail, $vnome, $vcpf, 'FROM: contato@beefladesign.com.br');
```

Assim o `$vemail` irá receber a mensagem, enviada por `contato@beefladesign.com.br`. Acredito que isto seja suficiente. Mas, dependendo de onde esteja executando o PHP pode haver outros problemas, algumas hospedagens compartilhadas, por exemplo, podem não permitir o envio ou exigir configurações adicionais. Se estiver em localhost [também pode precisar configurar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41487/15089). Se tiver muito azar, o próprio domínio, o DNS, pode definir quem está autorizado a enviar o e-mail, que faz alguns provedores de e-mail ignorem a mensagem enviada.

---

<sub><sub>Existem outros problemas no código, da maneira que está permite tanto um MySQL Injection, quanto um abuso de spam. Mas, isso é fora da questão.</sub></sub>

Comment: Obrigado InKeliz sigo estudando se der certo eu posto aqui!