# Não consigo enviar email localHost

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Não estou conseguindo enviar email do meu site localHost.

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> /* SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)  SMTP Error: Could
>   not connect to SMTP host.

```
<?php


// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta class
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

try {
     $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (Autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)

     $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
     $mail->Port       = 587; //  Usar 587 porta SMTP
     $mail->Username = 'sorezteste@gmail.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
     $mail->Password = 'xxx'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

     //Define o remetente
     // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=    
     $mail->SetFrom('sorezteste@gmail.com', 'soreze'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->AddReplyTo('sorezteste@gmail.com', 'soreze'); //Seu e-mail
     $mail->Subject ='Ben-vindo';//Assunto do e-mail


     //Define os destinatário(s)
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     $mail->AddAddress('sorezemf@gmail.com', 'Teste');

     //Campos abaixo são opcionais 
     //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
     //$mail->AddCC('destinarario@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario'); // Copia
     //$mail->AddBCC('destinatario_ocutlo@dominio.com.br', 'Destinatario2`'); // Cópia Oculta
     //$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // Adicionar um anexo


     //Define o corpo do email
     $mail->MsgHTML('conseguiiiiii'); 

     ////Caso queira colocar o conteudo de um arquivo utilize o método abaixo ao invés da mensagem no corpo do e-mail.
     //$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('arquivo.html'));

     $mail->Send();
     echo "Mensagem enviada com sucesso</p>\n";

    //caso apresente algum erro é apresentado abaixo com essa exceção.
    }catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Mensagem de erro costumizada do PHPMailer
}
?>
```

Comment: sobe em um server da hostinger (o webhost000) gratuito e testa, no localhost, dificilmente funcionará, pois você precisa configurar um monte de coisa

Comment: Indica algum hostinger gratuito...ta dificil te achar...o 000webhostinger nao funciona

Comment: Troque o `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` por `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` e veja se ocorre tudo bem, os demais passos estão em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41458/3635

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração e funcionou..no webhost000