# Acessar localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

Mudei recentemente minha porta do apache pelo xampp para a porta 465, mas como acesso meu localhost na net agora? Eu coloco `localhost:465/mail/` e não carrega.

Comment: qual o motivo da mudança? pois é só voltar ao normal

Comment: Preciso enviar email via SMTP pelo phpmailer, aí diz que a porta do smtp para enviar o email é essa

Comment: SMTP não tem nada haver com HTTP. Ou seja SMTP não abre via navegador, o que exatamente quer fazer?

Comment: Preciso enviar email via SMTP pelo phpmailer, aí diz que a porta do smtp para enviar o email é essa. Então eu mudei as portas do apache para 465, e agora meu localhost nao está mais funcionando, nao abre a página

Comment: Mas isso não tem sentido, 465 é pra usar no SMTP que é um protocolo, se você definir no Apache, que é HTTP você vai misturar duas coisas que nada tem haver.

Comment: Então no caso aqui: 
//Nome do servidor 
    $Mailer->Host = 'localhost:8080';
Ta certo?

Comment: Então como eu colocaria o host?
Eu preciso enviar emails pelo phpmailer que é pelo SMTP

Comment: SMTP é um serviço, se tiver um serviço de SMTP instalado na sua máquina vai funcionar, caso contrário não vai, se estiver usando um serviço de SMTP externo, como gmail, hotmail (outlook) ou yahoo, você tem que configurar o phpmailer como se fosse configurar o seu cliente de email, por exemplo Thunderbird ou Outlook, a resposta eu tentei explicar o melhor que deu https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259422/3635, leia com calma, pois esta claro que você ainda não entendeu o básico do que é SMTP e TCP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Apache é serviço que usa o protocolo HTTP (que é baseado em TCP)
- SMTP é um serviço e protocolo separado, que nada tem haver com HTTP e sites
- IMAP e POP3 são outros serviços e protocolos também diferentes

Cada um destes não tem relação com o outro, e SMTP, IMAP e POP3 não tem ligação alguma com desenvolvimento de páginas web.

Não faz sentido definir a porta do Apache como sendo a do SMTP, é o mesmo que esperar que um táxi te leve até o [Havaí](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hava%C3%AD), são serviços para coisas diferentes.

Apache é pra servir páginas web, SMTP tem que ter um programa próprio de **servidor SMTP**, geralmente hospedagens contratadas já servem isto, se quiser usar domínio próprio.

Agora se esta pensando em usar uma hospedagem que já tenha serviço de SMTP ou esta pensando em usar Gmail ou Outlook.com você deve configurar a porta diretamente no PHPMailer, resumindo, o caminho é este:

- Teu script vai dentro da pasta www ou public_html que pertence ao Apache
- O seu script se comunica via TCP com o SMTP usando o PHPMailer, ou seja não tem nada haver com o Apache
- O phpmailer envia os comandos para essa comunicação e espera a resposta
- A resposta do phpmailer que veio via TCP é salva em uma variavel
- Você exibe essa variavel via PHP se quiser

Resumindo Apache não tem nada haver com SMTP.

---

### Como resolver

- Servidor (programa) Apache usa porta 80 ou 8080 (ou qualquer outra que não conflite)
- Servidor (programa) SMTP usa porta 465 (se tiver algum programa de servidor para SMTP em sua máquia)

Se o SMTP for de um servidor ou serviço existente, **se a sua conta** de e-mail for na locaweb

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'email-ssl.com.br';
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'nazare@seu-dominio.com.br';
$mail->Password = 'senhadoemail';
```

Se o seu email for no Gmail:

> Gmail precisa liberar acesso, veja o passo a passo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41458/3635

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //Gmail usa TLS
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "nazare@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "sua senha";
```

Se seu email for no live:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl'; //Live usa TLS
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "nazare@hotmail.com";
$mail->Password = "sua senha";
```

Se o e-mail não usar SSL/TLS então deve remover a linha `$Mailer->SMTPSecure` (ou definir como `false`) e adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

Ficando algo como:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Define para autenticar
$mail->Host = '<seu host para SMTP>';
$mail->Port = <SUA PORTA, geralmente 587>;
$mail->Username = '<Seu usuário de e-mail, geralmente o e-mail completo>';
$mail->Password = "sua senha";
```

Comment: Com vários teste que eu faço a maioria da esse erro https://pastebin.com/YErcQV5k

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69557/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-nazare-lisboa).

Comment: E assim se salva uma pergunta :)

Answer (score 1):

Restaure seu locahost, provavelmente você leu errado sobre a porta do SMTP, ela é configurada dentro do PHP e não no localhost.

um exemplo de linha para configurar o SMTP em php:

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Caso tenha mais duvidas siga estes tutorias:

**Email Simples:** https://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-email-com-php/37216

**Email Com SMTP:** https://www.gn10.com.br/blog/dicas/envie-emails-php-smtp-gmail-google-apps/

**Importante**:

Alguns provedores de email como por exemplo o gmail, por padrão bloqueiam conexões de aplicativos menos seguros e para que o destinatário receba o email você tem que permitir a conexão no gmail remetente, no caso do gmail siga este tutorial: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Então no caso eu nao preciso mexer na porta do meu apache la no xampp? Posso deixar sendo 8080?

Comment: não, isso é desnecessário, você só edita a porta do apache caso ela entre em conflito com algum outro app que use a mesma porta, como porexemplo o skype.

Comment: Entendi. Eu fiz isso que voce disse, mas a página só fica carregando e depois fica toda branca (quando envio o email), e nao chega email nenhum no meu gmail. E eu tentei fazer um com o exemplo do github, mas diz que a conexao SMTP falhou

Comment: lembrando que o email remetente do gmail(o que vai enviar o email) precisa permitir, configure o gmail para permitir conexões desconhecidas, o próprio google tem este turorial.

Comment: Sim, eu já fiz isso e continua a mesma coisa