# PHPMailer (HTTP ERROR 500)

Tags: php, phpmailer, back-end

Estou usando apache 2 e o php8. 
 Ao carregar a pagina esta mensagem aparece 
 **"Esta página não está funcionando localhost não consegue atender a esta solicitação no momento.
HTTP ERROR 500"**

```
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';



// Criando uma nova instâcia
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// Definindo idioma
$mail->setLanguage('pt_br', 'PHPMailer/language/');

// Informando para usar SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

/*
  Habilitando debug SMTP
  0 = off (uso em produção)
  1 = Mensagens ao Cliente
  2 = Mensagens ao Cliente e Servidor
*/

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

/*
  Definir o nome do servidor de e-mail
  use $mail ->HOST = gethostbyname('email.gmail.com');
  se sua rede não suportar SMTP over Ipv6
*/

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

/*
  Defina o numero da porta SMTP - 587 para autenticação TLS,
  a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
*/

$mail->Port = 587;

// Define o sistema de criptografia a usar- ssl (depreciado) ou tals
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

// Se vai usar SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

// Usuário para usar SMTP authentication
// Use o endereço completodo e-mail do Gmail
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';

// Senha para SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Definir o remetente
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Curso');

// Definir o endereço para respostas
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Curso');

// Definir destinatario
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Destinatário');

// Definir o Assunto
$mail->Subject = 'Teste PHPMailer';

// Definir formato de mensagem HTML
$mail->isHTML(true);

// Corpo da Mensagem
$mail->Body = 'Uma mensagem <strong> Negrito </strong>';

// Corpo alternativo caso email não suporte html
$mail->AltBody = 'Mensangem simples';

// Envia a mensagem e verifica os erros
if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo "Erro no Mailer: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} else {
  echo 'mensagem enviada! <br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O PHPMailer precisa do `ssl_module` no apache. Precisa habilitar no arquivo `httpd.conf`.

Veja também as configuracões no `PHP.ini`

Tente e veja se consegue.

Informações baseadas nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40858/como-enviar-e-mail-do-localhost-usando-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mail-do-php)

Comment: Com as pesquisar que fiz acredito que ja tenha ativado e mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro